# Adjustable Sensitivity in a Light Sensor Circuit

Tags: sensor, light

I've designed the following circuit for detecting light and darkness and it seems to be working fine. I want to be able to set both LEDs to be off at a particular light sensitivity and to only come on when the light being detected deviates from this particular sensitivity. Any ideas on how to do this?
[image]

Comment: LDRs are non-linear with respect to light levels (3 orders of magnitude change over reasonable ranges.) Humans are, themselves, non-linear with respect to apparent brightness. Potentiometers tend to be linear with resistance, unless you pick an 'audio taper' one. You will also want to have some hysteresis in the circuit. (Believe me, you will.) A good design would take a little thought but it would start with some information from you. You should test out various light levels and measure the LDR resistance and report to us your perception of light and the Ohms in a table of values.

Comment: To give you an idea, from starlight to sunlight is 12 orders of magnitude change. Humans can see over that entire range. Dim lighting (between scotopic and photopic) is itself more than three orders of magnitude, with scotopic covering another three orders, and photopic covering the remaining 6 orders. It really does take some empirical work to do a really nice design where reasonable turn angles of a potentiometer correspond to reasonable lighting levels that a user would *appreciate well* for a light sensor device. It's not "slap it out" unless you're willing to live with annoying vagaries..

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to set both LEDs to be off at a particular light sensitivity and to only come on when the light being detected deviates from this particular sensitivity.

By "sensitivity" it seems you mean the LDR's resistance.

The conventional way an action is taken based on the resistance of an LDR is by using a comparator or op amp:

- the LDR's resistance is converted into a voltage using a resistor divider
- that voltage is compared using an op-amp or comparator to another pre-defined voltage
- the output of the comparator will either be high or low and can be used to turn on/off an LED or as an input into another decision making component

An example of this kind of circuit is shown here:

https://www.petervis.com/Education/ldr-op-amp-circuit/ldr-op-amp-circuit.html

and searches for "LDR comparator" will turn up more.

It seems you want to take an action when the LDR's resistance is measurably different from a certain preset value. The standard way to do this is with a "window comparator" circuit. This is a way to take an action when a voltage lies within a certain range. It can also be used to detect when a voltage lies outside a certain range. A web search for "window comparator" will give you a lot of circuit schematics and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer based on this alternative interpretation of your question:

> Your circuit has two LEDs. You want to remove those LEDs and turn on an new LED when either LED1 or LED2 would be on in the original circuit. That is, you want to detect when either transistor is turned on.

The idea is to use just resistors on the collectors of the transistors like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6NQPA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If either Q1 or Q2 is turned on then the PNP transistor Q3 will be turned on causing current to flow through the LED.

If both Q1 and Q2 are off then Q3 will also be off.

Your approach to this problem is a bit confusing because in a real product you wouldn't use two LDRs to sense the same light source. LDRs themselves are highly variable in operation -- even two made by the same manufacturer can can give you very different results from the same light source. Moreover, an LDR's resistance is highly dependent on exactly how the light falls on the sensor, so getting two to give you the same readings is pretty much impossible.

With a single LDR the op-amp/comparator approach is usually used and you can detect if the resistance is greater than, less than or in between a certain range very easily.